# Simon Ics Date Picker Dialog throws android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class net.simonvt.widget.DatePicker

Tags: android, android-datepicker, android-simon-datepicker

I'm using Simon's ICS Date Picker Library (https://github.com/SimonVT) in my android app.
I have a date button, if I make click on that button, it will show ics datepicker in dialog.
My Issue is, if I click on button, it doesn't show datepicker dialog, but it shows following error as :

```
03-02 10:46:59.521: E/AndroidRuntime(911): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class net.simonvt.widget.DatePicker
03-02 10:46:59.521: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
03-02 10:46:59.521: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
03-02 10:46:59.521: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
03-02 10:46:59.521: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
03-02 10:46:59.521: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
03-02 10:46:59.521: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at net.simonvt.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:103)
03-02 10:46:59.521: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at net.simonvt.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:74)



@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case START_DATE_PICKER_ID:
            mCalendar.setTimeInMillis(mStartMillis);
            year = mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            monthOfYear = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            dayOfMonth = mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            return new DatePickerDialog(ListPillBoxActivity.this, startPillBoxDateListener,
                    year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
        case END_DATE_PICKER_ID:
            mCalendar.setTimeInMillis(mEndMillis);
            year = mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            monthOfYear = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            dayOfMonth = mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            return new DatePickerDialog(ListPillBoxActivity.this, endPillBoxDateListener, year,
                    monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Bug pointed towards the following line on both cases :

```
 return new DatePickerDialog(ListPillBoxActivity.this, startPillBoxDateListener,
                    year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
```

every parameters is passed correctly to the datePickerDialog, but there is an issue in inflating dialog

Any Help Appreciated....

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem. The solution is to add three items to your style like in the DatePickerSamples:

```
<style name="SampleTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme">
    <item name="calendarViewStyle">@style/Widget.Holo.CalendarView</item>
    <item name="datePickerStyle">@style/Widget.Holo.DatePicker</item>
    <item name="numberPickerStyle">@style/NPWidget.Holo.NumberPicker</item>
</style>
```

Comment: your answer solved my issue, however still crashes on marshmellow

Answer (score 2):

Building on what @ham said,

after adding these lines as xml resources:

```
<style name="SampleTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme">
    <item name="calendarViewStyle">@style/Widget.Holo.CalendarView</item>
    <item name="datePickerStyle">@style/Widget.Holo.DatePicker</item>
    <item name="numberPickerStyle">@style/NPWidget.Holo.NumberPicker</item>
</style>
```

it is necessary to add this attribute to your `application` tag in AndroidManifest:

```
android:theme="@style/SampleTheme"
```

Answer (score 0):

also do not miss :

```
<!-- Copy one of these attributes to your own theme (choose either dark or light).
    <item name="numberPickerStyle">@style/NPWidget.Holo.NumberPicker</item>
    <item name="numberPickerStyle">@style/NPWidget.Holo.Light.NumberPicker</item>
-->
```